# Export ms access filtered form data issue?

Tags: excel, vba, ms-access

Hi all please be kind to me i am new and struggling with an issue. I have a split form that allows the user to search for or filter data in its bottom half: 
[image: Image of form]
The issue i am having is i am using from the research i have done

```
DoCmd.OutputTo acOutputForm, "frm Name here", acFormatXLS,
```

it works perfectly except i get the txt search box in there too I am beginner at VBA i get the basics but that is it. How could i not get the search box in my export to excel? can i write code that allows me to select certain txt boxes from the form? please help!

Answer (score 0):

Specify file name.

`DoCmd.OutputTo acOutputForm, "frm Name here", acFormatXLS, "FileName you want to use.xls"`

Seems file will be saved into last location navigated to in Windows Explorer.
So better specify folder path.

`DoCmd.OutputTo acOutputForm, "frm Name here", acFormatXLS, "C:\path\filename.xls"`